# Running Codeclimate locally

Tags: php, code-climate, code-climate-cli

I try to install Codeclimate via docker by reading the Codeclimate [readme docs](https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate).

In order to test Codeclimate locally. I made a new folder and put `hello.php` and `.codeclimate.yml`.

The following is my `hello.php`

```
<?php 

echo("Hello");
```

The following is my `.codeclimate.yml`

```
version: "2"
checks:
  argument-count:
    enabled: true
  complex-logic:
    enabled: true
  file-lines:
    enabled: true
  method-complexity:
    enabled: true
  method-count:
    enabled: true
  method-lines:
    enabled: true
  nested-control-flow:
    enabled: true
  return-statements:
    enabled: true
  similar-code:
    enabled: true
  identical-code:
    enabled: true
```

And I run the codecliate like the following via my terminal

```
docker run \
  --interactive --tty --rm \
  --env CODECLIMATE_CODE="$PWD" \
  --volume "$PWD":/code \
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --volume /tmp/cc:/tmp/cc \
  codeclimate/codeclimate analyze
```

It shows like `Starting analysis` and after waiting for a long time. I got a timeout error.

**Is something wrong with my configuration?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are running is pulling docker images named `codeclimate/codeclimate-structure` and `codeclimate/codeclimate-duplication`, if you go [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/codeclimate/codeclimate-structure/tags/) you'll notice they weighs ~2gb compressed, so taking a long time for the command to run is understandable.
You can expdite the command by pulling the image in advance by running `docker pull codeclimate/codeclimate-structure` & `docker pull codeclimate/codeclimate-duplication`.

I found out this is the case by adding the debug env var to the docker run command (`-e CODECLIMATE_DEBUG=1`), this can often come in handy when CLI tools behave abnormally.

Another thing code climate support and can help you in situations like this is setting higher timeout thresholds - `-e CONTAINER_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=1800`.

All of this info is present in the readme you've linked to in your question.
Hope this solves your problem.